# Bridge USB host to device

Tags: c++, c, linux, usb

In a nutshell, I'm developing an embedded system that requires, amongst other things, a bridge from a USB host port to a device port (this is just a first step, later the information transmitted will be filtered and altered).

Considering that this is basically a USB snooper/sniffer I figured that someone should have written a module capable of this, but my search has proven futile.

So, to the question: What's the simplest way to redirect a USB host to a USB device in Linux? The data must be identical, all descriptors and endpoints must match. It must be Linux friendly, I can code in C/C++ and have some experience with coding kernel modules, drivers, etc.

Comment: Basically you need to write your own driver, that should process the data in/out. You should start studying how an USB driver can be developed on Linux.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found previous work at http://www.elinux.org/BeagleBoard/GSoC/2010_Projects/USBSniffer

The simplest way to redirect a USB host to a USB device in Linux is in my opinion to use both the Linux' peripheral USB stack and Linux' gadget USB stack. Those stacks take care of the low level, so your code should only concern high level interfacing between those two stacks. Added bonus is that the sniffer (via usbmon) will come for almost free.

As that way will be dealing with the Linux kernel, it must be Linux friendly. The interface to both stacks is (at least) available in C. So, your conditions are met.

Comment: Thank you for the link, ill be checking it out later. And basicly yes, I went a little higher level. Not as flexible but I was pressed with some serious time constraints. If I ever get arround to improve this I would go that way too.